# x86 - x64 porting query

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, porting

We have an application written in C/C++ code running on 32-bits windows with 32-bit Hardware. My question is that if we upgrade our hardware to 64-bit and keep our OS 32-bit, does my application need a port to 64-bit? If it requires, what benefits will be there on a 32 bit OS?

Comment: You already have 64-bit hardware. Nearly every CPU sold in the past 8 years or so is 64-bit capable (with the exceptions of a few Atoms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardware doesn't count -- the OS does. Ergo:

- 32 bit hardware with 32 bit OS will run only 32 bit ports
- 64 bit hardware with 32 bit OS will run only 32 bit ports
- 64 bit hardware with 64 bit OS will run both 32 bit and 64 bit ports

The advantage of recompiling for 64 bit is access to more than 3GB ram and a speed increase if you operate on 64 bit datatypes or take advantage of compiler intristics (and a few others, but do not count on a immedate gain).

Comment: Building as 64-bit can give an immediate speed gain for some code just because more registers are available, and x86-64 calling conventions are more efficient than most crusty old 32-bit stack args conventions.  (But pointer-heavy data structures use more cache footprint.)  This is unique to x86 -> x86-64.  Most other ISAs like MIPS only gain more address space when going to 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the OS 32-bit, you must keep the app 32-bit, for many common values of OS. We, of course, cannot use telepathy to tell which OS you are using.